# HTML 5 Canvas Over-layed on top of a Web Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

The goal is to have fireworks come up over top of an existing web page, so that you can see both the existing page, and the fireworks exploding over top of it. I successfully got them over top of the page, however, now they do not fade out. I'm left with white build up over top of web page.

I have this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2EQ2w/1/

```
var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
    SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight,
    mousePos = {
        x: 400,
        y: 300
    },

    // create canvas
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    particles = [],
    rockets = [],
    MAX_PARTICLES = 400,
    colorCode = 0;

// init
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.body.insertBefore(canvas, document.body.firstChild);
    canvas.width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    canvas.height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    setInterval(launch, 800);
    setInterval(loop, 1000 / 50);
});

// update mouse position
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    mousePos = {
        x: e.clientX,
        y: e.clientY
    };
});

// launch more rockets!!!
$(document).mousedown(function(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        launchFrom(Math.random() * SCREEN_WIDTH * 2 / 3 + SCREEN_WIDTH / 6);
    }
});

function launch() {
    launchFrom(mousePos.x);
}

function launchFrom(x) {
    if (rockets.length < 10) {
        var rocket = new Rocket(x);
        rocket.explosionColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360 / 10) * 10;
        rocket.vel.y = Math.random() * -3 - 4;
        rocket.vel.x = Math.random() * 6 - 3;
        rocket.size = 8;
        rocket.shrink = 0.999;
        rocket.gravity = 0.01;
        rockets.push(rocket);
    }
}

function loop() {
    // update screen size
    if (SCREEN_WIDTH != window.innerWidth) {
        canvas.width = SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
    }
    if (SCREEN_HEIGHT != window.innerHeight) {
        canvas.height = SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
    }

    // clear canvas
    context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.001)";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    var existingRockets = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < rockets.length; i++) {
        // update and render
        rockets[i].update();
        rockets[i].render(context);

        // calculate distance with Pythagoras
        var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mousePos.x - rockets[i].pos.x, 2) + Math.pow(mousePos.y - rockets[i].pos.y, 2));

        // random chance of 1% if rockets is above the middle
        var randomChance = rockets[i].pos.y < (SCREEN_HEIGHT * 2 / 3) ? (Math.random() * 100 <= 1) : false;

/* Explosion rules
             - 80% of screen
            - going down
            - close to the mouse
            - 1% chance of random explosion
        */
        if (rockets[i].pos.y < SCREEN_HEIGHT / 5 || rockets[i].vel.y >= 0 || distance < 50 || randomChance) {
            rockets[i].explode();
        } else {
            existingRockets.push(rockets[i]);
        }
    }

    rockets = existingRockets;

    var existingParticles = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
        particles[i].update();

        // render and save particles that can be rendered
        if (particles[i].exists()) {
            particles[i].render(context);
            existingParticles.push(particles[i]);
        }
    }

    // update array with existing particles - old particles should be garbage collected
    particles = existingParticles;

    while (particles.length > MAX_PARTICLES) {
        particles.shift();
    }
}

function Particle(pos) {
    this.pos = {
        x: pos ? pos.x : 0,
        y: pos ? pos.y : 0
    };
    this.vel = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };
    this.shrink = .97;
    this.size = 2;

    this.resistance = 1;
    this.gravity = 0;

    this.flick = false;

    this.alpha = 1;
    this.fade = 0;
    this.color = 0;
}

Particle.prototype.update = function() {
    // apply resistance
    this.vel.x *= this.resistance;
    this.vel.y *= this.resistance;

    // gravity down
    this.vel.y += this.gravity;

    // update position based on speed
    this.pos.x += this.vel.x;
    this.pos.y += this.vel.y;

    // shrink
    this.size *= this.shrink;

    // fade out
    this.alpha -= this.fade;
};

Particle.prototype.render = function(c) {
    if (!this.exists()) {
        return;
    }

    c.save();

    c.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';

    var x = this.pos.x,
        y = this.pos.y,
        r = this.size / 2;

    var gradient = c.createRadialGradient(x, y, 0.1, x, y, r);
    gradient.addColorStop(0.1, "rgba(255,255,255," + this.alpha + ")");
    gradient.addColorStop(0.8, "hsla(" + this.color + ", 100%, 50%, 0)");
    gradient.addColorStop(1, "hsla(" + this.color + ", 100%, 50%, 0)");

    c.fillStyle = gradient;

    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.flick ? Math.random() * this.size : this.size, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    c.closePath();
    c.fill();

    c.restore();
};

Particle.prototype.exists = function() {
    return this.alpha >= 0.1 && this.size >= 1;
};

function Rocket(x) {
    Particle.apply(this, [{
        x: x,
        y: SCREEN_HEIGHT}]);

    this.explosionColor = 0;
}

Rocket.prototype = new Particle();
Rocket.prototype.constructor = Rocket;

Rocket.prototype.explode = function() {
    var count = Math.random() * 10 + 80;

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var particle = new Particle(this.pos);
        var angle = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;

        // emulate 3D effect by using cosine and put more particles in the middle
        var speed = Math.cos(Math.random() * Math.PI / 2) * 15;

        particle.vel.x = Math.cos(angle) * speed;
        particle.vel.y = Math.sin(angle) * speed;

        particle.size = 10;

        particle.gravity = 0.2;
        particle.resistance = 0.92;
        particle.shrink = Math.random() * 0.05 + 0.93;

        particle.flick = true;
        particle.color = this.explosionColor;

        particles.push(particle);
    }
};

Rocket.prototype.render = function(c) {
    if (!this.exists()) {
        return;
    }

    c.save();

    c.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';

    var x = this.pos.x,
        y = this.pos.y,
        r = this.size / 2;

    var gradient = c.createRadialGradient(x, y, 0.1, x, y, r);
    gradient.addColorStop(0.1, "rgba(255, 255, 255 ,255)");
    gradient.addColorStop(0.1, "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");

    c.fillStyle = gradient;

    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.flick ? Math.random() * this.size / 2 + this.size / 2 : this.size, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    c.closePath();
    c.fill();

    c.restore();
};
```

Which was built off this base:

http://jsfiddle.net/dtrooper/AceJJ/

Does anyone know how I can get these fireworks to fade out? Or get the particle to fade out after it hasn't moved for a few milliseconds?

Comment: You mean you want the canvas to cover (hide) the other content on the page and then fade out to reveal the other content?

Comment: @showdev, No, sorry for the confusion. I'm trying to get the fireworks to display on top of an existing page (represented by the "Hello" in the fiddle). So you can see the existing page, but there are fireworks happening over top of it.

Comment: I see what you mean. It seems that the fireworks use `fillRect()` to clear (fade out) old fireworks. So anything behind that "rect" will not show. I had [some luck by using `clearRect` instead](http://jsfiddle.net/AceJJ/278/), but the fireworks no longer leave trails, which is not optimal.

Comment: @showdev, while not optimal, definately better than what I was able to come up with. Thanks for the help! I'll keep playing with clearRect and see what I can come up with. If you throw it as an answer, I'll accept. Definitely enough to work with. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely have this with fading trails:

http://jsfiddle.net/LgjG8/

Just set up a second off-screen canvas that has a reduced [global alpha](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#Attributes):

```
// create 2nd canvas
var canvas2 = document.createElement('canvas'),
    context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

canvas2.width = canvas.width;
canvas2.height = canvas.height;

// reduce alpha of second canvas
context2.globalAlpha = 0.8;
```

Then instead of simply wiping the canvas clean each frame, copy the first on-screen canvas to the second. This will produce a faded copy of the visible canvas due to the lowered global alpha value. Then wipe the first canvas before copying the faded version back. Finally, just update the canvas as normal. This will produce a trail.

```
// produce faded copy of current canvas
context2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
context2.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);

// redraw faded copy on original canvas
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
context.drawImage(canvas2, 0, 0);
```

I didn't really look through your code so you might need to play with this a little, but you get the idea.

Comment: Beautiful, really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to have the content visible, you can try to change the way the trails are generated and use the `clearRect`. Instead to have the trails done by the `c.fill()` you can make it to be done by particles, so you can view them.

In the Rocket.prototype.render you can do this:

```
//c.fill();

var particle = new Particle(this.pos);
particle.shrink = Math.random() * 0.05 + 0.93;
particle.size = 10;

particles.push(particle);
```

And the trails will be visible then.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cw7P2/)

---

Before edited answer (not working as asker expected):

In the `loop()` function you have a really small alpha, making that the fireworks are not fading out.

Try to change:

`context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.001)";`

to

`context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)";`

Hope it helps!

Comment: The problem is that the OP wants other content on the page to show behind the canvas.

Comment: Added a way to show the trails using the clearRect function so the page behind the canvas can be showed.

Comment: +1 Very nice! That also got rid of the black "matte" behind the rockets.

Answer (score 1):

The fireworks use `fillRect()` with a low opacity to clear (fade out) old fireworks. As a result, nothing behind the canvas will show.

However, you can use `clearRect()` instead so that the canvas does not have a solid background. The problem with this is that the fireworks don't leave nice trails because there is no low opacity fill to fade them out.

Not optimal, but at least the fireworks are in front of the other page content. I wish there was a `clearStyle` you could set to low opacity but, sadly, no.

```js
// clear canvas
//context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)";
//context.fillRect(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
context.clearRect(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AceJJ/278/)